# Map Fn+Direction Keys to Home, End, etc

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

On Apple keyboards, one of my favorite features on Linux is that if I hold <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, it triggers the <kbd>Home</kbd> key, the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> triggers <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> triggers <kbd>PageUp</kbd>, and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> triggers <kbd>PageDown</kbd>

This makes text navigation super easy: without leaving the home row I can easily navigate around documents and lines.

Due to reasons (touchbar :'[), I'm not going to be using Apple hardware anymore and I'm now on a ThinkPad X1 Yoga. I would like to remap a lot of the keys to mirror what happens on my Apple keyboards.

Here is the result of my pressing and releasing the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key:

```
KeyPress event, serial 53, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x13c, subw 0x0, time 110088308, (71,-372), root:(1262,292),
    state 0x0, keycode 151 (keysym 0x1008ff2b, XF86WakeUp), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False


KeyRelease event, serial 53, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x13c, subw 0x0, time 110088318, (71,-372), root:(1262,292),
    state 0x0, keycode 151 (keysym 0x1008ff2b, XF86WakeUp), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Here is the result of pressing and releasing <kbd>Left</kbd>:

```
KeyPress event, serial 53, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x13c, subw 0x0, time 110150520, (-320,-320), root:(871,344),
    state 0x0, keycode 113 (keysym 0xff51, Left), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 53, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x13c, subw 0x0, time 110150591, (-320,-320), root:(871,344),
    state 0x0, keycode 113 (keysym 0xff51, Left), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Finally, here is the result of pressing <kbd>Home</kbd>:

```
KeyPress event, serial 53, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x13c, subw 0x0, time 110552974, (56,-93), root:(1247,571),
    state 0x0, keycode 110 (keysym 0xff50, Home), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 53, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x13c, subw 0x0, time 110553021, (56,-93), root:(1247,571),
    state 0x0, keycode 110 (keysym 0xff50, Home), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I'm reading a lot of contradictory information on `xmodmap` and `xkbcomp`. I'm not sure what I have to do, but I imagine that it involves mapping a shortcut that doesn't yet exist.

What am I missing and how do I proceed here?

Comment: most keyboard `Fn` keys do not reach the OS; you appear to be lucky in this regard.  i'd look into using a udev `hwdb` override to turn that key into an additional modifier (Hyper, assuming you have Win/Super keys already), and then you can probably coax XKB into interpreting Hyper+Arrows as your home/end/pgup/pgdn keys.